# Shell scripting- Running operations on statistics extracted from json of aws cloudwatch statistics using bash

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, jq, aws-cli

I am running `aws cli aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2010-02-20T12:00:00 --end-time 2010-02-20T15:00:00 --period 60 --namespace AWS/EC2  --extended-statistics p80 --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-0b123423423` in a
loop and extracting the metrics from json(using jq) in the below format for around 10-20 instances.

```
Illustrative JSON

    {
      "Label": "CPUUtilization",
      "Datapoints": [
        {
          "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T12:15:00Z",
          "Unit": "Percent",
          "ExtendedStatistics": {
            "p80": 0.16587132264856133
          }
        },

Instance-ABC
19.514049550078127  
12.721997782508938  
13.318820949213313  
15.994192991030545  
18.13096421299414 

Instance-BCD
19.5140495 
12.7219977 
13.3188209
15.9941929  
18.1309642
13.3188209
15.9941929  
18.1309642
```

How can i calculate and run operations from the values in above output to get results like below in using Bash scripting

```
Instance above 70% 
Instance-ABC
Instance-BCD

Instances below 20% 
Instance-EFG
Instance-HIJ
```

---

I'm currently retrieving statistics with:

```
for i in $(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.["Reservations"]|.[]|.Instances|.[]| .InstanceId' | sort -n); do
  echo "Instance $i"
  aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2019-02-20T15:00:00T --end-time 2019-02-20T18:00:00 --period 60 --namespace AWS/EC2 --extended-statistics p80 --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$i \
    | jq '.Datapoints[].ExtendedStatistics[]'
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please show some illustrative JSON input and the jq query that produces the output that is shown.

Comment: Sure Cyrus
@peak This is the code i use
for i in $(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.["Reservations"]|.[]|.Instances|.[]| .InstanceId' | sort -n)
do
echo "Instance $i" 
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2019-02-20T15:00:00T --end-time 2019-02-20T18:00:00 --period 60 --namespace AWS/EC2  --extended-statistics p80 --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$i | jq '.Datapoints[].ExtendedStatistics[]' 
done

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the mapping between your posted sample input and your posted expected output. Make sure the output is **the output** you expect go get given **the input** you provided and not some other output you'd get from some different input. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Also, make sure the JSON in the question is **actually valid**. If it can't be copied-and-pasted into jq, it can't be used to test an answer.

Comment: BTW, in general, I'd tried to avoid using bash or awk in favor of doing all the work (except the calls out to the external commands) in jq; it's more than capable of floating-point math, string manipulation (including generating arbitrarily-formatted output), &c.

Comment: Also, make sure we know what you want. Does "above 70" mean an *average* above 70? A *peak* above 70? Something else? Don't make people guess.

Comment: Also, consider building stub functions -- something like `getInstanceList() { printf '%s\n' "this is the first line getInstanceList is supposed to output" "this is the second line..." "etc"; }` lets someone actually test their answers, whereas `getInstanceList() { aws ec2 describe-instances | ...; }` can't be run by people who don't actually have an EC2 environment on-hand.